# Relating taking the power set to logical operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm an undergraduate math major reviewing "Mathematical Proofs, A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" and specifically the first two chapters on sets and logic. I'm trying to find ways to write set operations in terms of logic and vice-versa. The one that's giving me the most trouble is the power set.

Let A(x) over the domain S be a necessary condition to be an element of the set A. Or in other words let A be the solution set to an open sentence A(x), where x is an element of S.

What I'm looking to figure out is a way to use logic to construct an open sentence such that it's solution set is the power set of A.

It seems like there isn't any convenient way to do this with logical expressions. I suspect you have to do something like create n other open sentences R(x)i with the same domain S, (R(x)1, R(x)2, ..., R(x)n), and the solution set for each open sentence one creates must be equal to one of n unique subset of A in the power set of A (where the cardinality of the power set is n). Then one must create n numbers of new if/then open sentences, (if R(x)i then A(x)),   consisting of each unique open sentence and A(x), and connect all of those if/then open sentences with n-1 "or" connectives to create a new open sentence P (x). And I'm hoping the solution set to that open sentence P(x) would be equal to the power set of A, but I'm really not sure about that.

The goal of the if then statements would be to show that each of the newly constructed open sentences' solution sets was a subset of A.

Am I on the right track? Is there a more convenient way to represent the power set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to enumerate each of the subsets of $A$ (and besides, what if $A$ were infinite)?  Instead, you can just describe what it *means* to be a subset of $A$.

You want to write a formula $P(x)$ which is true iff $x$ is an element of the power set of $A$.  That is, you want $P(x)$ to be true iff $x$ is a subset of $A$.  What does it mean that $x$ is a subset of $A$?  Well, it means that every element of $x$ is an element of $A$.  That is, if $y\in x$, then $A(y)$ is true.  So you can take $P(x)$ to be $$\forall y (y\in x\Rightarrow A(y)).$$

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $A$ can be thought of as a function $f$ from $A$ to the set $\{T, F\}$ of truth values.  So, the problem boils down to representing ``$f$ if a Boolean-valued function on $A$'' as a first-order logic formula (perhaps as an element .  Once that it done, your answer is:
$$
\{ \{x : f(x) = T\} \; : \; \mbox{$f$ is a function from $A$ to $\{T, F\}$} \; \}.
$$

Alternatively, the power set of $A$ can be thought of as the Cartesian product of ``$|A|$ copies of $\{T, F\}$.''  Hope this helps.